# Custom phone verification in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, verification, sms-verification

AWS Cognito SDK provides two methods:

1. `GetUserAttributeVerificationCode`
2. `VerifyUserAttribute`

The first one generates a 4-digit code for the provided attribute (email or phone) and the second one verifies the provided attribute with the provided code.

I want to use my own service for sending SMS verification codes. Unfortunately, AWS doesn't seem to provide an API, where I can manually set a 4-digit code on a cognito user awaiting confirmation inside something like a custom attribute `phone_code_verification` and then call `VerifyUserAttribute` to verify that code.

Is there a way to achieve this ?
Also, AWS Cognito throws `LimitExceededException`, `TooManyRequestsException` and other useful errors, so I would like the proposed method to be wrapped in the same AWS logic and not have to implement rate limit or request limits myself.